# Image src outputs garbled text in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Here is a code snippet:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" class="comic-link" 
   href="//files.explosm.net/comics/Dave/adblocker2.png"     
   data-target="#comicModal">
  <div class="thumb-home thumbnail">
    <img id="comic" src="//files.explosm.net/comics/Dave/adblocker2.png">
  </div>
</a>
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
$('a.comic-link').on('click touchstart', function() {
  var url = $(this).attr('href');  
  $(".comic-modal .modal-body").html('<img src="' + url + '"/>');
});
```

The images appear on the webpage but if I click on a link then instead of images garbled text appears inside the modal. There is no errors in console.
Please let me know If I need to provide more details.

**UPDATE**

It only happens with Explosm Comics and not with Dilbert.

Comment: `</img>` is invalid, it should be `.html('<img src="' + url + '"/>');`

Comment: Thanks but it did not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `$('.comic-modal').modal('hide');` directly above the JavaScript snippet and now the Modal works.
I still don't know the explanation yet though.

Answer (score 0):

Does adding `http:` in front of your url solve the problem? Something in your environment might not be handling the protocol-relative URL properly.

Comment: No, it does not solve the problem. It only happens with explosm comics though and not with dilbert and others.

Comment: Could you provide a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) containing the full code of your page, or at least the modal and the relevant jQuery code?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, there are only image in the modal-body.

I guest your image garbled title or footer?

Maybe you can try adding a `modal-lg` class at modal-dialog.

Or change your window's size to make the modal bigger?

Or add this to your css

```
.modal-body img {
    width:100%;
}
```